# search a database record using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

can someone please help me with the my search function on my code? Im new into php and im using codeigniter framework for the development.

search view

```
<div id="admin-col">
                    <div>
                    <?php echo form_open('search_admin/search_admins'); ?>
                    <?php
                        $data = array('name'=>'search', 'id'=>'search');
                        echo form_input($data);
                    ?>
                    <?php
                    $data = array('name'=>'submit', 'id'=>'submit', 'value'=>'Search Admin');
                    echo form_submit($data);
                    ?>
                    </div>
```

controller

```
class Search_admin extends CI_Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->load->library('security');
        $this->load->library('tank_auth');
        $this->load->model('users/usermodel');
    }

    function index()
    {
        if(!$this->tank_auth->is_logged_in())
        {
            redirect('/auth/login');
        }
        else
        {
            $data['user_id'] = $this->tank_auth->get_user_id();
            $data['username'] = $this->tank_auth->get_username();

        }
    }

    function search_admins()
        {
            $data['query']=$this->usermodel->search_admins($this->input->post('search'));
            $this->load->view('admin/users/search_result',$data);
        }
}
```

model

```
class UserModel extends CI_Model {

    function _construct() {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->load->library('security');
        $this->load->library('tank_auth');
        $this->load->model('users/usermodel');
        $this->load->database();
    }

    function search_admins($search)
    {
    return $query = $this->db->get_where('users', array('username ='=> '$search'))->result();

    }

}
```

view for the result

```
<div id="admin-col">
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <th>ID</th>
                            <th>Username</th>
                            <th>Email Address</th>
                            <th>Actions</th>
                        </tr>
                        <?php foreach($query as $row){?>
                        <tr>
                            <td><?php print $row->id; ?></td>
                            <td><?php print $row->username; ?></td>
                            <td><?php print $row->email; ?></td>
                            <td><?=anchor('userslist/get_Admin/'.$row->id, 'Edit');?>&nbsp;|&nbsp;<?=anchor('userslist/deleteAdmin/'.$row->id, 'Delete');?></td>
                        </tr>
                        <?php }?>
                    </table>


                    </div>
```

Comment: it doesn't display any result

Comment: Just a thought, but why dont you auto load all of those library's?  They dont effect performance unless you are using them and you are loading them at least twice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you had

```
array('username ='=> '$search')
```

in your `search_admins()` function

try

```
array('username'=> $search)
```

instead